# Issue in Password Stength : regex

Tags: angularjs, regex

**Markup**

```
<form ng-submit="doRegister(registerForm);" novalidate name="registerForm">
    <input type="password" name="Password" ng-model="register.Password" 
        ng-pattern="/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/"/>
    <span ng-show="registerForm.Password.$error.pattern" class="help-block">
        min 1 lower char, 1 upper char, 1 digit and one special char 
    </span>
    
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid" >
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

I am testing the Password Strength with min 1 lower char and 1 upper char and 1 digit and one special char

> I am testing this string: a1A@s.com //Failed
>
> I am testing this string:
> 12345aA!                 //Passed

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Was the failure for the first test case intentional? Because I do it see how it doesn't match your criteria

Comment: Look into zxcvbn, much better password strength validator.

Comment: @Geoff : Please explain more about zxcvbn

Comment: https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

Comment: @Toto: Read the question there carefully. How carelessly you marked it duplicate !!!! My question regex params are completely different from that question !!!

Comment: Use this one if you prefer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2394092/372239

Answer (score 2):

It is failing because `@` is not part of your character class in last lookahead. You can also simplify your regex to this:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@!$#%]).{3,}$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZdpZS/7)

Comment: `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` should be replaced by `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])`.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed `min 1 lower char, 1 upper char` part in question.